# Can email recipients unsubscribe when I'm sending to a Google group?

Tags: email, sendgrid, google-groups

I currently have an automated email that I'm sending to a google group using SendGrid. There is a user within that group that does not want to receive these emails, and wants to unsubscribe.

Will a normal SendGrid unsubscribe group work here? I'm not sure what will happen when they unsubscribe since I am sending through a group. If not, what are my options here?